# Is it possible to export labels/ratings from ViewNX2?

Tags: nikon, software

I have downloaded the same set of NEF images onto two different machines (using TransferNX). On one machine, I have gone through the images in ViewNX2 and rated/number labelled the images.

Is it possible to somehow either:

1. export the labels/ratings so I can apply them to the copy of the images on the other machine (in ViewNX2); or
2. export the images WITH the labels/ratings so I can copy them onto the 2nd machine (and essentially replace the existing copy)?

Answer (score 1):

ViewNX can embed Labels and Rating into XMP metadata of the images, so you can copy them to another computer with View/Capture NX and your marks will be visible.